# Ultrastar Deluxe on Ubuntu

Tags: apt

I'm trying to install Ultrastar Deluxe. I have installed recommended packages but there are some errors. The icon appears on my computer but i can't open it.

```
1.ultrastar-deluxe_1.1.0-svn-20120608-1_i386.deb
2.ultrastar-deluxe-data_1.1.0-svn-20120608-1_all.deb
3.ultrastar-deluxe_1.1.0-svn-20120608-1_amd64.deb
Errors:
dpkg: error processing package libavformat52 (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libavformat52
```

Comment: From where you got the Ultrastar Deluxe? What is your Ubuntu version?

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 16.04 LTS you can use newer package version from [the same PPA](https://launchpad.net/~tobydox/+archive/ubuntu/ultrastardx):

```
mkdir -p ~/Downloads/ultrastar-deluxe
cd ~/Downloads/ultrastar-deluxe
wget https://launchpad.net/~tobydox/+archive/ubuntu/ultrastardx/+files/libportmixer_2.0+svn20140510-3_amd64.deb
wget https://launchpad.net/~tobydox/+archive/ubuntu/ultrastardx/+files/ultrastar-deluxe_1.1.0+svn20151230-2_amd64.deb
wget https://launchpad.net/~tobydox/+archive/ubuntu/ultrastardx/+files/ultrastar-deluxe-data_1.1.0+svn20151230-2_all.deb
wget https://launchpad.net/~tobydox/+archive/ubuntu/ultrastardx/+files/ultrastar-deluxe-songs_20100506-3_all.deb

sudo apt-get install ./*.deb
```

On newer versions of Ubuntu can follow [official README](https://github.com/UltraStar-Deluxe/USDX) or packaging [recipe from ArchLinux AUR](https://aur.archlinux.org/cgit/aur.git/tree/PKGBUILD?h=ultrastardx-git):

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install git automake make gcc fpc libsdl2-image-dev libavformat-dev libswscale-dev libsqlite3-dev libfreetype6-dev portaudio19-dev libportmidi-dev liblua5.3-dev libopencv-videoio-dev

git clone https://github.com/UltraStar-Deluxe/USDX
cd USDX
./autogen.sh
./configure
make
sudo make install
```